# Graph request as User from backend Azure Ad

Tags: java, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I've recently faced a problem.

My frontend use Oauth2 to authenticate my user on Azure (Organization). This giives me multiple information containing idToken and accessToken.

My Backend uses AADResourceServerWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to authenticate the user thanks to the idToken put in the Authorization Bearer header from the frontend.

Unitil here everything works well. I can get the connected user with this:

```java
public static String getConnectedUserEmail() {
        return (String) ((AADOAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getAttributes().get("preferred_username");
    }
```

I use my backend app credentials to contact the graph api on behalf of the API itself.

Though, following Azure Ad documentation, I cannot query group/calendar on behalf of the API, I have to do it on behalf of the user.
To respect SOLID principles, I want to make the request from the backend, but on behalf of the user.
I cannot find any information about that.

So here is my final question: How can I make a graph API request in my backend on the behalf of the user?
Knowing that trying to use the tokenValue (idToken) of the user or the accessToken value returns invalid credentials from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

You requested `GET /groups/{id}/calendar` to get group calendar as you said.

You can call Graph API with the access token using **on-behalf-of flow**, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow#use-the-access-token-to-access-the-secured-resource).

[image]

There is a sample using the On-Behalf-Of flow: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-webapi

**Note:** Make sure the following delegated permission is added.

[image]